# Animating the hiding/showing of a view with a Toggle

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

Here is my code

```swift
@State private var show = false

...

Form {
    Toggle(isOn: $show, label: { Text("Show the text?") })
    if show {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}
```

With a button that would have the action `self.show.toggle()` I can animate the slide with a
`withAnimation{}` statement but I'm not sure how to do it with a toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This could give you better Animation:**

```
  Form
  {
    
    Toggle(isOn: $show, label: { Text("Show the text?") })
    
    Group
    {
        if show { Text("Hello World") } else { EmptyView() }
    }
 }
   .animation(.easeOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `.animation(.easeOut)` modifier to your Text view like so -

```
@State private var show = false

...

Form {
    Toggle(isOn: $show, label: { Text("Show the text?") })
    if show {
        Text("Hello World")
           .animation(.easeOut)
    }
}
```

By adding this modifier, any changes applied to the view will be animated.

From [Apple's basic animation tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions) - *When you use the animation(_:) modifier on a view, SwiftUI animates any changes to animatable properties of the view. A view’s color, opacity, rotation, size, and other properties are all animatable.*

You can also animate specific part of the view, or the way you want it to appear, for example set the color to black with opacity of 0 and if `show == true` it sets back to 1 (fully visible)

```
@State private var show = false

...

Form {
    Toggle(isOn: $show, label: { Text("Show the text?") })
    if show {
        Text("Hello World")
           .foregroundColor(show ? Color.black : Color.black.opacity(0)) // if show is true than foreground color is black, if show is false than color is black with opacity 0.0 (not visible)
           .animation(.easeOut)
    }
}
```